# Excluding an array/list of directories in find

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to use an array supplied from a config file to exclude a list of directories from `find`. A simple example of the array looks like:

```
excludedDirList2[0]='*.'
excludedDirList2[1]='node_modules'
```

I've been messing around with the `-prune` and `! -path` options but I can't figure out a way to dynamically read the array, generate the `find`, and make it actually work.

An example of a command that works but doesn't dynamically read the array

```
find $dir -type f -name "hidden.txt" ! -path "${excludedDirList[1]}" ! -path "${excludedDirList[0]}"
```

Comment: `find` is not a BASH command, it is a program for which there are manpages etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it works, just add `!` and `-path` in front of every element of the array and pass it to `find`.

```
 excludedDirList2=('*.' 'node_modules')
 findargs=()
 for i in "${excludedDirList2[@]}"; do
       findargs+=('!' '-path' "$i")
 done
 find "$dir" -type f -name "hidden.txt" "${findargs[@]}"
```

Comment: `"${findargs[@]}"` will quote the entire test and pass them as single command line arguments. That won't work. You only want quotes around the pathname.

Comment: @ooga No, you are wrong. The array expansion with `@` as index will properly quote everything.

Comment: @ooga: You are talking about `"${findargs[*]}"`; not `"${findargs[@]}"`

Comment: @anishsane, no I'm not.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I think I've figured it out. You are adding the '!', the '-path', and "$i" all as separate array elements. So that's why it will work properly.